I use HandWiki as my primary online encyclopedia. Would or should people edit my links to Wikipedia?
As many may have already know, I live in a region where my national firewall blocks the IP addresses of Wikipedia (and other WikiMedia content sites, so I can't access them using domain fronting).
A few weeks ago, I found HandWiki. Due to their focus being on primarily science and technology as well as lack of political content, it's passing the censor (at least for now).
Q1: If I put a link to HandWiki in my post(s), would or should others edit it into a link to Wikipedia?
Q2: What miscellaneous information do you think should be brought up in this post? (Content quality of HandWiki in particular).

Q1) you can't compare them, so if I change to it Wikipedia the content may not be the same, right? I prefer we should keep it as it is. Indeed, web archive version is better. Hey, can't you use the web archive, too?

Web Archive is deemed too inclusive by my government, shame... @kelalaka

I guess that is true for Tor, too even with the bridges.

For context, while HandWiki claims that it tries to be an alternative to Wikipedia rather than a clone of it, at least at the moment it seems that pretty much all of its cryptography content has been imported verbatim from Wikipedia. So ordinarily I would say that there's little point in linking to a copy rather than to the original source, although the firewall issue does complicate things a bit.


Q1: If I put a link to HandWiki in my post(s), would or should others edit it into a link to Wikipedia?

I would think it very unwise to change any working links to correct information to another source. Those kind of edits should not be accepted. Fortunately, I haven't seen many edits in that kind of sense.
Of course, it would be fine for other users to add a link to Wikipedia or any other information source either in the post or in the comments, but I assume that would not pose a problem to you.

Q2: What miscellaneous information do you think should be brought up in this post? (Content quality of HandWiki in particular).

Well, if it is a Wiki I suppose you could propose edits yourself, so first of all you could fix their content. Otherwise, if you see any errors then please put those in the post as well, or indicate that you only refer to some part of the information that is not faulty. Having a more direct link to a section could help in this case.

Note that neither Wikipedia nor HandWiki or anything else are original sources of information. Pointing to a paper or standards document such as an RFC is highly encouraged - assuming that it augments or helps explain the post well.

Thanks. The note is really important, and I personally link to original sources whenever possible; online encyclopedias I think are good when people need introductory contents.
